# passing data using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
var i = 3;
$("#add_driver").click(function () {
  $("#add_driver_section").replaceWith(-- -- --);
  i++;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'step-3.php',
    data: {
      c: i
    },
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response.status);
    }
  });
});
```

this is my first page

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['c'])){
    echo $_GET['c'];
}else echo 'error';
?>
```

this the second page.
i need to pass the value of i from the first page to the php script in the second using ajax.

I get this error in the `#result` element

> Notice: Undefined index: c in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\carenquery\step-3.php on line 5

what am i doing wrong?

---

HTML

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
  <div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_driver">
    <span>
      Add another Driver <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What's an issue you're facing? Is there any error?

Comment: What sort of element is `#add_driver`? Is it a `<button>` or `<input type="submit">`? If so, is it part of a `<form>` at all?

Comment: @Phil `<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
     <div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_driver">
     <span>
     Add another Driver
     <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </span>
     </div>
    </div>` this is the code for add-driver and yes it is a part of < form>

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava _Notice: Undefined index: c in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\carenquery\step-3.php on line 5_ is the error i am getting

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar where are you seeing that error? Is that what is being shown via `$('#result').html(response)`, ie that is the `response` you get back from the AJAX request?

Comment: @Phil i m getting this error in the page where the value has to be passed to

Comment: i am new to ajax . this is my very first code in ajax

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Are you seeing that error string injected into your `#result` element from the AJAX response or are you opening `step-3.php` in your browser directly?

Comment: @Phil yes it is injected into #result

Comment: Ok, and `step-3.php` **only** contains `<?php
 print_r($_POST['c']);
?>`, correct? Check your browser's _Network_ console. You should see the AJAX POST request when you click your element. Click on the request in the console and check the parameters sent (usually under _"Form Data"_). Check the response tab; is it the same error message?

Comment: @Phil it is not showing any error message

Comment: Please read my comment again. I asked you to check a very specific set of things. It would be great if you could post screenshots of those things so we can all see what's going on

Comment: @Phil can you ckeck my edited code and tell me if there is something wrong?

Comment: There's absolutely no reason you should have had to switch to a GET request. There was nothing obviously wrong with your original code nor is there anything obvious with the latest code. To debug this, you should definitely be looking in your browser's consoles (code **and** network). You need to look at the AJAX request, at what parameters it is sending (either via POST or GET) and at the response that is coming back from your server

Comment: can i see the code in `step-3.php` on line 5?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
var i = 3;
$("#add_driver").click(function () {
  $("#add_driver_section").replaceWith(-- -- --);
  i++;
  $.get('step-3.php',{c:i},function(x){$('#result').html(x)});
});
```

and this is for step-3.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['c'])){
        echo $_GET['c'];
    }else echo 'Get Nothing';
?>
```

Comment: The `isset()` is a nice check to do but what else does this offer over OP's code? `$.post` is just an alias for `$.ajax` with certain parameters pre-set

Comment: OP could even use `$('#result').load('step-3.php', {c:i})` if they wanted to really shorten it down

Comment: the output is "posted nothing"!!

Comment: because you are clicking only a div element, so instead of using `$.post` replace it with `$.get` then update your `step-3.php`

Comment: @Phil, she wants to pass data using ajax. and i teach her the simplest way to pass data using ajax. she just have to study about the code i showed her.

Comment: `$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'step-3.php',
   data: { c: i},
   success: function(response) 
         {
    alert(response.status);
   }
  }
    );`        -i changed my code to this and ammended all the changes you guys suggested but it is still not working. the response status is _"localhost says undefined"_.